# Iphone corners of UIButton transperancy possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

While using UIVIEW I put an image to the background and added a UIBUtton, but since the corners of the button can be set one color from IB, it does not match with the background image of UIView. is there a way to add alpha to that corners so they are invisible? or any other solution?

There are samples of using custom ui buttons but I dont know how to add them to where I want in UiView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the color to clearColor it is the one that is a little half black half white square.